# Vue3: data undefined when I separate mount command from create command

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

New to js, new to Vue - apologies if this is a basic error.

I'm trying to follow the [Vue3 guide](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#composing-with-components) with mixed success, and I'm currently struggling with accessing data from a mounted app. If I create and mount in one command, I can access the data; if I split create and mount into two separate commands, I can't. I've read through the Vue app lifecycle and that hasn't helped.

Code:

```js
const data1 = { a: 1 }
const data2 = { a: 2 }

const vm1 = Vue.createApp({
    template: '<h1>test1</h1>',
    data() {
        return data1
    }
}).mount('#app1');

const vm2 = Vue.createApp({
    template: '<h1>test2</h1>',
    data() {
        return data2
    }
})

vm2.mount('#app2');

console.log(vm1.a)
console.log(vm2.a)
```

`vm1.a` is defined, `vm2.a` is not defined.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/weegolo/2z9m1gsc/3/)

How do I define data in an app with separated create and mount commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vue.createApp` returns the [*application instance*](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#creating-an-application-instance), while `Vue.createApp().mount()` returns the *root component instance*, which contains the data properties you're seeking. In your example, `vm2` is the application instance.

To fix your example, assign `vm2` to the result of `mount()`:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp(...)
const vm2 = app.mount('#app2')
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pgq7t6y3/)